# how to call function on movie load in actionscript instead using event listener?

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is the code to call function using event listener:

```
 var listListener:Object = new Object();
 listListener.change = function() { changeImage(); }
 thelist.addEventListener("change", listListener);
```

Is there a way to call the function simply when the frame is loaded using the same function as above?

Thanks
agus

Comment: are you sure this is AS3? Looks like an AS2 way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're calling this from within an instance of a Class that extends EventDispatcher (i.e. MovieClip, Sprite, etc.)...

Use this to dispatch an event of that type (i.e. "change").

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```